# Is there any way to "turn down the volume" of a particular user on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

There are a couple of people I follow on Tumblr that post a lot and when they do it seems to be several posts at a time. While I do want to see their posts (I am following them after all), I would rather see a bit *less* of them. To be fair, it's the volume of reposts (or "reblogs" in Tumblr terminology) that I want to reduce not their original content.

There is the **ignore** option - but I'm assuming that that will remove *everything* and I don't want that.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You could write a userscript to hide this very easily. Do you have an example of a blog that you want to turn down the volume to?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Tumblr does not provide any settings to change the frequency of given blogs' posts' appearing on the Dashboard.

It is possible to filter out and hide posts from your Dashboard based on words that show up in their titles, contents, and/or tags using the third-party browser extension [Tumblr Savior](http://bjornstar.com/tumblr-savior) (available for Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera). However, you will need to have specific keywords in mind, and this, too, will completely hide (from your Dashboard, not actual blogs) any posts contain at least one match in terms on your blacklist, based on the options you set.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is by using Tumblr Savior to blacklist the name of the blogger themselves. The posts then show up on the dash as a one-line post notification: NAME made a post containing 'NAME' click to show. The notification will include any tags the blogger included. You can then choose to click on the post to see it, or keep scrolling.

If the blogger happens to post topics you DO like, whitelist those topics and posts containing that word or tag will always appear, regardless of blacklist status.